# Nested If statement in Excel - Check if value exists in one column or the other, both, or neither

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have three columns.

One is of IDs that are prioritized (`noCHARMY`), and the right most two are IDs underneath a particular folder (`folders_30dir` and `folders_33dir`).

```
noCHARMY       folders_30dir       folders_33dir
337            204                 204
365            337                 365
444            444                 444
723            560                 907
```

I want to set up a nested conditional that tells me whether or not the ID in `noCHARMY` is:

1. In `30dir`
2. In `33dir`
3. In both `30dir` and `33dir`
4. In neither `30dir` or `33dir`

```
noCHARMY       Which
337            30dir
365            33dir
444            Both
723            Neither
```

I have a `IF(COUNTIF())` function that can help me find if they are in both, but as soon as I add the other three conditionals, it gets messy. How would I combine everything into one function? Is it possible?

For Both: `=IF(AND(MATCH(A2,B:B,0),MATCH(A2,C:C,0)),"Y","N")`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution for exactly 2 folders

You can simply use a sum of checks that returns an indicative number.

In the screenshot below, the formula returns 0 if the value doesn't appear in neither column, 1 if only in the first, 2 if only in the second, and 3 if in both columns

[image: screenshot_1]

The formula used here is

```
=SUM((E6=$F$6:$F$9)*1)+SUM((E6=$G$6:$G$9)*2)
```

You can the combine this with the `SWITCH()` function which is just a method to avoid nesting multiple `IF()` functions:

[image: screenshot_2]

the formula used here is

```
=LET(
    case,SUM((E6=$F$6:$F$9)*1)+SUM((E6=$G$6:$G$9)*2),
    SWITCH(case,
        0,"Neither",
        1,"30dir",
        2,"33dir",
        3,"Both"
    )
)
```

### Solution for a variable number of folders

In case a solution for a larger number of folders is needed, the following is less intuitive but allows for any number of folders:

[image: screenshot_3]

using the formula

```
=LET(
    value,$B4,
    array,$C$4:$I$7,
    names,$C$3:$I$3,
    matches,MMULT(TRANSPOSE(value=array)*SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(array)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(array),1,1,0)),
    folders,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX(names,1,FILTER(matches,matches<>0))),
    IFERROR(folders,"None")
)
```